# HP ALM Authorization failed while build job from Jenkins [Running in Unix as Master]

Tags: unix, jenkins, hp-uft, hp-alm

We were tried to integrate HP ALM with Jenkins to Execute our test cases as post build actions. It will triggered after Build and deployment.

Here Jenkins runs in unix machine as Master and we make our windows machine as slave. we installed ALM plugin also and configured job accordingly to Execute Test set in ALM.

While Build Job in Jenkins we got the below error log in console output as Authentication failure.

But it got success when we have Windows machine as Master and slave in Jenkins.

> Started by upstream project "HPTest" build number 11
>   originally caused by:
>    Started by user tibco
>   Building remotely on Slave in workspace C:\Users\C887755\workspace\Jenkins\workspace\HPTest\label\Slave
>   [Slave] $ C:\Users\C887755\workspace\Jenkins\workspace\HPTest\label\Slave\HpToolsLauncher.exe -paramfile props03072015154620620.txt
>   "Started..."
>   Timeout is set to: 3000000
>   Run mode is set to: RUN_LOCAL
>   Failed to login. Please contact system administrator for help.
>   Description: Authentication failed. Verify your user name and password.
>   Error: Cannot Login to QC: Authorization failed.
>   Build step 'Execute HP functional tests from HP ALM' changed build result to FAILURE
>   Finished: FAILURE

Kindly Help us to get rid of it. Searched lot in web Can't right path to solve it.

Your help is much Appreciated.

Thanks,
Madhan

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a similar issue like [this](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Performance-Center-Support-and/HP-ALM-Performance-Center-11-52-and-Jenkins-Integration-Issues/td-p/6425032#.VZvBC8Xboeg). Do you have HP passport login? If yes, then you can download the fix.
Hope it helps.